Sci-fi dystopian movie with a guarded wall separating the countryside
A (maybe small or indie) sci-fi dystopian movie with a guarded wall separating the countryside (maybe hilly on a coast) and the people outside don't know what's on the other side.
I think the wall was silver metal with a door / revolving door in it and may have been patrolled. Might have been a father and daughter in a wood cabin on the outside.
It wasn't too old, maybe early 2000s (not 70/80s). That's all I can remember.  Not even sure what I watched it on.
It's not an indivisible wall or dome and takes place above ground. The wall may be slotted metal not solid but on top of a hill so you can't tell what's on the other side.  And it's not more mainstream like new YA, doomsday, colony, or city of embers.
I did a lot of searching but could not find anything thanks!

In roughly which year did you watch this?

I wish I could remember - not too old maybe early 2000s (not 70/80s) and I tried a lot of google searches but could not find anything  thanks!

And what was on the other side?

I don't remember, something that terrified the main character I think - one reason I wanted to watch it again to see if I missed hints during the movie but may be one of those that just disappoints you in end.

I wonder if this is two stories getting confused, and one of them is Stardust?
